# 4. Define a function with one parameter (position) to find an element by the position stored in the array and to return the details of element found

Tags: javascript, arrays

my javascript assignment wants me to find an element in an array and return the details in the form of a string. My problem is that it also says "In the function, code random access algorithms to operate on the arrays and return the athlete’s information as a string. " I just want someone to explain this for me I'm not asking for anyone to write my code for me I just don't understand what a random access algorithm is and how I would use it to get and return the array element. If someone could just explain or dumb down what I have to do so my stupid brain can understand. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume your professor is talking about the way that arrays operate, as the values inside them get saved in the **random access memory** *("RAM")*.

This is just an assumption based on your question's specifications: I think your professor refers to **random access algorithms** to the algorithms that change the values in the array and by consequence the **RAM**.